# Why are Java's methods of converting color codes to standard form are very different from mine?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm building a game and I have a system for loading images into the game, but returning them to the screen as blocks.

The two main colors I use in the map as of now are: 0x000000 (Black) and 0x9EEDFF (Light Blue). I have this system in which I return a certain block to the screen with a certain color.

```
if (blocks[x + (y * width] == 0x000000) return VoidBlock.block;
if (blocks[x + (y * width] == 0x9EEDFF) return IceBlock.block;
```

When I first ran it, it didn't work. All I got was an empty abyss. :/

But, what I did was I managed to output the colors of the blocks and I got these very strange numbers: -6361601 for black and -16777216 for light blue. I attempted to decode them via online with decimal to hexadecimal converters, but nothing seemed to give me my color. It gave me like, 134861234 or something, and it didn't really help a lot.

So, my question is, how does Java get that number and how I can ensure that my above code will match it? Right now, the only code that's running my program is:

```
if (blocks[x + (y * width] == -6361601) return VoidBlock.block;
if (blocks[x + (y * width] == -16777216) return IceBlock.block;
```

Thanks in advance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
public void loadLevel(String pathway) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Level.class.getResource(pathway));

        int image_width = image.getWidth();
        int image_height = image.getHeight();
        pixels = new int[image_width * image_height];

        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That was my loadImage() method for taking the image and converting it to that. Now, here's my generateLevel() method:

```
public void generateLevel() {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            blocks[x + (y * width)] = pixels[x + (y * width)];
            System.out.println(blocks[x + (y * width)]);
        }
    }
}
```

It all comes together in this method:

```
public Block getBlock(int xPos, int yPos) {
    if (xPos < 0 || xPos >= width || yPos < 0 || yPos >= height) return EmptyBlock.block;

    if (blocks[xPos + (yPos * width)] == -6361601) return StoneBrickBlock.block;
    //if (blocks[xPos + (yPos * width)] == 0x9EEDFF) return StoneBlock.block;
    //if (blocks[xPos + (yPos * width)] == 2) return LavaBlock.block;
    if (blocks[xPos + (yPos * width)] == -16777216) return IceStoneBrickBlock.block;

    return EmptyBlock.block;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that sets those numbers?  There is no way that `0x000000` can ever equal anything other than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, -16777216 corresponds to alpha = 255, red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0.  You almost certainly don't care about the alpha, so you should ignore it when you do your comparison.

So you could write

```
if (blocks[x + (y * width)] & 0xFFFFFF == 0x000000)
```

which checks whether the value is "black plus some alpha".

Likewise, -6361601 corresponds to alpha = 255, plus your "light blue" (9EEDFF).  So the same trick will work there too.

```
  if (blocks[x + (y * width)] & 0xFFFFFF == 0x9EEDFF)
```

It seems your only issue was your need to ignore the alpha value.

Comment: 100% sure. It's a light blue in the image, but I don't know why java won't run it properly.